# How to play video using software like on MX player?

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I have troubled in playing a video that is not supported by hardware I want to create a simple video player that can play any video even it is not supported by hardware. I like the way how mx player did it. Can any one help me how to play a video like in MX player. I have this basic syntax but it only plays hardware supported videos. Here's my code

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    Uri uri = uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"
                + R.raw.videointro);

    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.start();
```

Comment: You will need to implement native C libraries and video codecs in order to play non-support media. It's no easy task.

Comment: @StevenTrigg Can you give me another options how I can play that video in my videoView. Is it possible to play when I convert my video to another format? If does what format it will be?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write intent and for that please pass the video url. Then android will identify apps which will able to play video then you need to pick/select one.

Comment: I need to create my own video player not via intent.